# How can I deploy firebase function?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am having issues in trying to deploy firebase functions. If I try to do firebase -deploy I end up with below error:

````
(base) mdarifulislam@Arifuls-MacBook-Pro firebase % firebase deploy

=== Deploying to 'amrai-bangladesh'...

i  deploying functions
Running command: npm --prefix "$RESOURCE_DIR" run lint

> functions@ lint /Users/mdarifulislam/Documents/GitHub/AmraiBangladesh/firebase/functions
> eslint .

✔  functions: Finished running predeploy script.
i  functions: ensuring necessary APIs are enabled...
✔  functions: all necessary APIs are enabled
i  functions: preparing functions directory for uploading...
i  functions: packaged functions (40.4 KB) for uploading
⚠  functions: Upload Error: Server Error. read ECONNRESET

Error: Server Error. read ECONNRESET
(base) mdarifulislam@Arifuls-MacBook-Pro firebase % ```


How can I solve this problem?
````

Comment: Try to logout and login back, through the CLI:  `firebase logout` ... `firebase login`

Comment: @RenaudTarnec Unfortunately, does not work, the same error appears

Comment: If you are having problem deploying to Cloud Functions using the Firebase CLI, and the error message isn't helpful, you should contact Firebase support directly.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's some sort of blocking that's going on in Bangladesh. You can try VPN while deploying. Works for me.